# Resistance between terminals A and B

Tags: resistors, resistance

I found the Req of the whole circuit at first, then tried re-assembling the circuit and still I couldn't get the right answer.

Any idea on how I should proceed in this exercise?

[image]

I'm not looking for any answers, just a walkthrough.

Step 1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGGDqu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Step 2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdwU1I.png)</sup>

Step 3:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCsfpD.png)</sup>

Comment: There are two pairs of resistors that can be immediately combined. Do that and add a second schematic showing the result. The next step will then be immediately obvious. There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It saves the schematic inline with your question.

Comment: I've moved your Step 1 down below the original to maintain chronological order. You're on the right track but you've managed to divide most of the resistor values by 1000 somehow. Double-click each component to fix the resistance adding 'k' for kilo or just the numbers for ohms. How did R2 become 1.2? When you've fixed all the errors can you see what components to combine next?

Comment: @Transistor then I have two pairs of resistors that are parallel, I join them and then I have three resistors in series, when I add the resistors all together, should it give me Req between the terminals? Because the answer is still wrong when I do that...

Comment: No, you don't have three resistors in series. In Step 2 (which I've labelled for you so that we know which diagram we're talking about) R1 and R2 are in parallel and R3 and R4 are in parallel. Combine them in Step 3 but fix the value of R2 in Step 1 and 2 first. I pointed this out already. It should be 0.3 kΩ. You can use 'V' to flip a component vertically and 'H' to flip horizontally if you need to switch text to the other side of a component for legibility.

Comment: Step 3 looks good. Now you've two resistors in series. Can you see which ones?

Answer (score 1):

You proceeded via reasonable steps, but you stopped short of the answer.  What you did up to step 3 looks correct.

To proceed from there, note that R1 and R2 are in series.  The result of that is in parallel with R3.  Solve for that and you're done.